# Failed to instantiate file from module: The specified list does not exist

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, css, feature-activation

I'm trying to add new pictures in a pre-existing library name *My_lib* using solution deployement. Here is my Element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="Images_MDS" Url="My_lib">
    <File Path="Images_MDS\nuageux.png"     Url="nuageux.png"       Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="Images_MDS\soleil.png"      Url="soleil.png"        Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="Images_MDS\pluvieux.png"    Url="pluvieux.png"      Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

When activating the feature I received the error message write in the title. 
What am I doing wong ? I've read already the other post about this very subject and they wasn't helpfull. I'm using sharepoint Foundation 2010. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the URL of library again.You can find the correct URL for library in address bar when you open this library.

It is not necessary that, URL and Library name are always same.If library name has been renamed then your 'My_lib' library may have different URL.

Comment: You're right but unfortunetely the library name and url are correct. I've checked it :(. The library that I want to fill is a custom document library. Does that making any difference ? The Url attribute in Module tag specify the Url of the document library that I want to the file to be stored in. The Path attribute of the file tage specify the path of files inside the module, And the Url attribute of the same tag specifiy the location where the files will be stored inside the document library after deployement. Are we ok ?

Comment: Yes,It is OK.Could you please try it without type attribute? or use Type=Ghostable

Comment: I've put Ghostable in the Type attribute of the File tag instead of GhostableInLibrary. The deployement goes well but I can't see my pictures in the document library :(.